# C# Language Specification ver 5.0 and List

Tags: list, specifications, c#-5.0

I've started reading the C# Language Specification that comes with Visual Studio:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Specifications\1033`

In chapter `1.6.7.4 Events` I found the following:

> An event is a member that enables a class or object to provide
>   notifications. An event is declared like a field except that the
>   declaration includes an event keyword and the type must be a delegate
>   type.
>
> Within a class that declares an event member, the event behaves
>   just like a field of a delegate type (provided the event is not
>   abstract and does not declare accessors). The field stores a reference
>   to a delegate that represents the event handlers that have been added
>   to the event. If no event handles are present, the field is null.
>
> The
>   `List<T>` class declares a single event member called Changed, which
>   indicates that a new item has been added to the list. The Changed
>   event is raised by the OnChanged virtual method, which first checks
>   whether the event is null (meaning that no handlers are present). The
>   notion of raising an event is precisely equivalent to invoking the
>   delegate represented by the event—thus, there are no special language
>   constructs for raising events.
>
> Clients react to events through event
>   handlers. Event handlers are attached using the += operator and
>   removed using the -= operator. The following example attaches an event
>   handler to the Changed event of a `List<string>`.
>
> ```
> using System;
> class Test
> {
>   static int changeCount;
>   static void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>       changeCount++;
>   }
>   static void Main() {
>       List<string> names = new List<string>();
>       names.Changed += new EventHandler(ListChanged);
>       names.Add("Liz");
>       names.Add("Martha");
>       names.Add("Beth");
>       Console.WriteLine(changeCount);     // Outputs "3"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> For advanced scenarios where control of the underlying storage of an
>   event is desired, an event declaration can explicitly provide add and
>   remove accessors, which are somewhat similar to the set accessor of a
>   property.

I got quite surprised when I found out about `List.Changed` event, so I created a new console application in Visual Studio 2012 and set target framework to .NET 4.5.

When I tried to compile the application (using both Visual Studio and Developer Command Prompt) I got the following error:

> error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Changed' and no extension method 'Changed'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something here? I used ILSpy to see class definition and I don't see `Changed` event.

Comment: You are not missing anything.  The List<> class doesn't have a Changed event.  Read C# language specification example code as just examples, not real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `List<T>` is defined earlier in the spec, in the section titled **Other function members**:

> The following table shows a generic class called List, which
>   implements a growable list of objects.

This `List<T>` class has no relationship to the class `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, except that they have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything, `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` doesn't have any `Changed` event.

I think this is meant to be just an example, not the specification saying how the `List<T>` class should look like. (That wouldn't make much sense, the C# specification specifies only a tiny part of the library, certainly not any specific collection classes.)

Also notice that the specification talks about some general `List<T>` class, not the specific `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class.